# Can't pass a User model to Policy in Laravel.

Tags: laravel

I am getting a strange error in my routes:

> Argument 1 passed to UiLogPolicy::read() must be
>   an instance of PeopleTable, instance of
>   Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser given

I don't have anything suspicious in my UILog policy;

```
public function read(PeopleTable $user, UiLogTable $uiLog)
{
    return $user->can(['read', 'manage_logs'], true);
}
```

Comment: you are passing a wrong instance,what told your error.Verify this.

Comment: @ImtiazPabel Laravel handles passing the User Model itself - I cant explicitely choose a model to pass. I can only define the second argument. 
My code looks like 'Gate::allows('read', $uilog);' 
And laravel passes the authorized user without asking me. That is why I cant choose the instance myself...
I have already setup the PeopleTable in auth.php config (before asking the question on SO), by the way.